# How to register 'abi-encoded' in bscScan? (noob)

Tags: solidity, abi, constructor, bscscan

I made a token with '.sol' through 'Remix'.

After that, I copied my token abi, pasted it to 'https://abi.hashex.org/' , and checked the construction function, and it was empty.
[image]

What is the 'constructor arguments ABI-encoded' I need to get?
[image]

I don't know what they want from me.

If I leave it blank and submit it, an error appears.
[image]

Comment: how are you importing the dependency contracts? can you show code